# Passing custom data is different between focus and change event jQuery

Tags: jquery, eventhandler

I have a fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/ws1hz5uf/ which demonstrates how to pass extra data to the target event.

The first button (Go 1) trigger **focus** on the text input

```
<div class="enclosing1">
<input type="text" id="example">
<label for="example">Test label 1</label>
<input type="button" id="test1" value="Go 1">
</div>

$(".enclosing1").on("click","#test1", function() {
    $("#example").trigger("focus", [true]);
});

$(".enclosing1").on("focus", "#example", function(event, isAutoTrigger) {
    console.log(isAutoTrigger);
});
```

The second button (Go 2) trigger **change** on the dropdown list.

```
<div class="enclosing2">
<select id="test-select">
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
<label for="test-select">Test label 2</label>
<input type="button" id="test2" value="Go 2">
</div>
$(".enclosing2").on("click", "#test2", function() {
    $("#test-select").trigger("change",[true]);
});

$(".enclosing2").on("change", "#test-select", function(event, isAutoTrigger) {
  console.log(isAutoTrigger);
});
```

Looking at the console I can see clearly that **focus**' event handler can not receive the extra param from the trigger call while that of **change** can. Considering the consistency in the description of *trigger* and *on* methods of jQuery API, I don't understand why there is such discrepancy in how event handler treats extra data. Could anyone please shed some light for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause: **focus** is a *special event* of jQuery and its event handler does not accept extra parameter. Hence change the event from **focus** to **focusin** solve the problem.